# How to fetch data from table using foreign key using json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I have a products table where each product has multiple images in Image table on rails application. These two tables are connected using foreign key i.e product_id on Image table. Now I want to fetch data from both the tables in **json format based on product id**. What code do I need to put on my controller in show method? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller

```
def your_function_name
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])  #to find product with id
    @product_images = @product.images
    respond_to do |format|      #for dual functionality JSON as well as HTML
        format.html { redirect_to @product }
        format.json { @product_images }
    end
end
```

For Json you would also like to have a view for json. for this you might use gem like jbuilder or rabl.
for example in you use jbuilder you have to create a view like

your_function_name.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract! @images, :first_variable_of_images, :second_variable_of_images, :created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this simplest way

```
 def show
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    product_images = product.images

       respond_to do |format|
       format.json {:images => product_images}
       end

    end
```